# Arduino Nano + RC522 + w5500 Ethernet Module

Tags: arduino-nano, ethernet, spi, rfid

has anyone had any experience wiring up an arduino nano with an RC522 RFID module and a W5500 ethernet module? i can get each of them to work individually, but i cannot get them to work together. i am not super experienced, but this seems to be some sort of SPI collision

The RobotDyn Ethernet Module i am using:

[image: RobotDyn W5500 ethernet module]

The RFID Module i am using:

[image: RC522 RFID module]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both modules use SPI then they should each have a separate pin connected to the slave select.

This lets you select which module you are talking to every time you start a communication. If the modules are well behaved then its MISO pin will be in high impedance when it is not selected instead of pulling it low or high trying to send data.

If it is not well behaved then you will need to add a buffer.

Comment: thanks for your comment @ratchet-freak, it turned out the RC522 is not well behaved (as you indicated) and i have to set the SS pin HIGH before the Ethernet module would work properly